# Postgres: Query that returns percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

My SQL is rusty. I have a table that logs all HTTP requests and their status. What I am wanting to do is create a query that shows the percentage of the results where status='404 NOT FOUND' PER DAY

here is what the table looks like

```
articles=# select * from log limit 1;

             path              |       ip       | method | status |              time          |   id
-------------------------------+----------------+--------+--------+----------------------------+---------
 /article/balloon-goons-doomed | 198.51.100.108 | GET    | 200 OK |     2016-07-01 06:02:39-05 | 1688046
```

I was able to get the raw counts like this, but not sure how to get the percentage

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', time) "day", count(*) as count FROM log WHERE 
status='404 NOT FOUND' group by 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [conditional aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Form PostgreSQL 9.4, there is an explicit syntax (`agg_func(...) FILTER (WHERE <predicate>)`) for it:

```
SELECT   date_trunc('day', time) "day",
         COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND')::NUMERIC
           / COUNT(*) "not found / total"
FROM     log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

For earlier versions, you can simulate that with the `CASE` expression (you just need to make sure, that the `CASE` expression's `THEN` branch always be non-`NULL`; leaving out the `ELSE` branch will generate `NULL`s in all the other cases, so `COUNT()` won't count them):

```
SELECT   date_trunc('day', time) "day",
         COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '404 NOT FOUND' THEN status END)::NUMERIC
           / COUNT(*) "not found / total"
FROM     log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: THANKS this was initially returning 0 but worked with a slight change

SELECT   date_trunc('day', time) "day",
         ROUND(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE status = '404 NOT FOUND')::NUMERIC
           / COUNT(*) * 100 ,2) "404 Percentage"
FROM     log
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1

Comment: @hypnotoad yes, OFC: I forgot the cast to `numeric` (`int / int` is `int`, which will always be `0` for values between `0` and `1`). `100.0 * COUNT(...) FILTER (...) / COUNT(...)` would be a valid solution as well, if you want percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok to select the total count in a sub query?

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', time) as day, count(*) / totalCount.count * 100 as percentage
FROM log,
(
    SELECT count(*) FROM log
) totalCount
WHERE status='404 NOT FOUND' group by 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: ERROR:  column "totalcount.count" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: Oh yeah, as far as I know count doesn't require group by. I think you can completely remove that `group by 1 ORDER BY 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
The below sample query will give the total record count and also the count of records that are satisfying your condition. (This is MYSQL example)

```
SELECT
((COUNT * 100)/TOTAL_REC_COUNT) AS PERCENT
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as TOTAL_REC_COUNT,SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS='404 NOT FOUND' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT
FROM test.sample_table
) TMP
```